# Calculating remaining CIDR ranges with Python

Tags: python, networking

I need assistance in calculating in Python the remaining CIDR ranges after i use a subnet.

Example:
I want to use a wide range of 10.0.0.0/15 and from it to calculate what available ranges i have left if i substract 10.0.0.0/16 ( the answer should be 10.1.0.0/16 )

But this gets trickier if i want to substract /24 or other actions.

Is there something that can help with this inside Python?

thank you

Comment: You can try to save each subnet’s first and last address then formulate a solution from there.

Comment: But how would i calculate remainings? Example if i have 10.1.0.0/16 and i want to substract a mask /24 from it ( 10.1.0.0/24 ) what would remain? Is there any library that does this?

Comment: Reserving 10.1.0.0/24 uses range 10.1.0.0-10.1.0.255 then you can use this range to indicate usable ranges as such(ignoring the address classes) [0.0.0.0-10.0.255.255] and [10.1.1.0-255.255.255.255]. I don’t know any libraries that does this.

Comment: Any idea on a formula to use for this? the /15 /16 /24 are just examples, i would need to split a lot and i need an automation for this

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-ipaddress-module/ - Not sure if this has the solution to your needs.

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very easy to do with netaddr module.

```
from netaddr import *
subnet1= IPSet(IPNetwork("10.0.0.0/15"))
subnet2 = IPSet(IPNetwork("10.0.0.0/16"))
# symmetric difference
result = subnet1 ^ subnet2
print(result)
```

result: `IPSet(['10.1.0.0/16'])`

if you want to subtract /24

```
from netaddr import *
subnet1= IPSet(IPNetwork("10.0.0.0/15"))
subnet2 = IPSet(IPNetwork("10.0.0.0/24"))
# symmetric difference
result = subnet1 ^ subnet2
print(result)
```

result:

```
IPSet(['10.0.1.0/24', '10.0.2.0/23', '10.0.4.0/22', '10.0.8.0/21', '10.0.16.0/20', '10.0.32.0/19', '10.0.64.0/18', '10.0.128.0/17', '10.1.0.0/16'])
```

Comment: Hi, what if i want to use just the mask for subnet2 mask=16 and get a result of both IPs from the example subnet1= IPSet(IPNetwork("10.0.0.0/15"))? I would expect result to be 10.0.0.0/16 and 10.1.0.0/16. In other words, i don't know what IP i want to substract, i just know i want an available /16 mask based on the 10.0.0.0/15 subnet

Answer (score 1):

Consider your example: you assigned a `/16` subnet of your `/15` net, so you split your total host address space in two, i.e. the one you assigned, which has a `0` value for the 16th bit, and the one which is still free, and has a `1` for the 16th bit.

Now suppose you had a `/14` net. Assigning a `/16` subnet would leave you with 3 free `/16` subnets, i.e. the ones with respectively `01`, `10`, `11` in positions 15-16. Of course since two of them have `1` in position 15 we may also say you have one `/15` subnet (`10.2.0.0/15`) and one `/16` subnet (`10.1.0.0/16).

And so on.

So when you assign a `/24` subnet from your original `/15` net you are creating `2**9` (512) `/24` subnets: the one you assigned and 511 more. Or you may say you are left with one `/16`, one `/17`, ..., one `/24` free subnet.

I don't know of any libraries for that, but as you see the calculations are simple enough. On the other hand, developing a system to keep track of many subsequent assignments is far from trivial...

If you want a list of all the subnets, this will do:

```
def ip2int(dec_ip):
    t = 0
    for e,k in enumerate(reversed(dec_ip)):
        t += k*16**(e*2)
    return t

def int2ip(int_ip):
    ip = []
    for e in range(4):
        ip.append(int_ip % 256)
        int_ip //= 256
    return list(reversed(ip))

def subtract_ip(mask, width, sub_width):
    subnets = []
    int_mask = ip2int(mask)
    delta = int(2 ** (sub_width - width))
    for d in range(1, delta):
        subnets.append(int2ip(int_mask + d*2**(32-width)))
    return subnets

subtract_ip([10,0,0,0], 14, 16)
[[10, 0, 1, 0], [10, 0, 2, 0], [10, 0, 3, 0]]
```

Comment: Interesting, but what should this do? I am asking because if i want to use the subnet 10.0.0.0/24 from a range of 10.0.0.0/15, i am getting a list of numbers that eventually leads to [10, 0, 511, 0] which is not an IP or the remaining subnets after i take out 10.0.0.0/24 ( which is what i want ). Thank you for the idea

Comment: No, I just checked and you get all the /24 subnets remaining, from 10.0.1.0 to 10.1.255.0

Comment: Awesome, is there a way to add a different required mask to this logic? Example i already made the first request for 10.0.1.0/16 and now i want to see if i can get a 10.0.2.0/28 inside the wide mask of 10.0.0.0/14? A reformulated question would be how to work with this if i have a wide mask and my desired mask that i want to check inside of it?

Comment: To check if a submask is inside a wider one just check that the common (most significant) bits are equal; again, supposing you maintain a list of all the remaining available subnets, you can check if a narrower subnet is available by checking the common MSBs between that new subnet and one of those in the list.

Comment: Note: I corrected a typo in the code in my answer, sorry for that

Comment: Sorry for coming back late, but if i run mask ([10,0,0,0], 15, 16) i was expecting to receive 10.0.0.0/16 and 10.1.0.0/16. What is wrong here? Thank you

Comment: It returns the _remaining_ subnets. In other words, the assumption is you assigned 10.0.0.0/16 so the only subnet of 10.0.0.0/15 still available is 10.1.0.0/16. If you want to see all the subnets, including the "assigned" one, just replace `for d in range(1, delta):` with `for d in range(delta):`

Comment: But it seems that when I "fixed" a typo in the answer I accidentally modified a statement, so instead of printing e.g. 10.1.0.0 it would print 10.0.0.1. Sorry, fixing it

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful if it works. At the moment it prints out only an incorrect 10.2.0.0 if i choose subtract_ip([10,0,0,0], 14, 16). I looked into all the versions that you posted and none of them returned the 10.1.0.0 result of an 15 16. This would be the exact answer i need if you could take a look at it! Thank you so much for helping. Would you like me to ask this in a different question?